# loading log4j.properties for log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

please check the attached image of project structure, let me know if i positioned log4j2.properties right.
also have a look at versions of jars I am using.
I wrote a simple program to print logs on console. in order to achieve this I wrote log4j2.properties file as follows.

## Root logger option

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

log4j.appender.file= org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.file.Target=System.out

log4j.appender.file.Layout=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.file.Layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

Main program is as follows.(also shown in image)

```
package goldensource.track.logs;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil;

public class TestLogger {
    
    
    private Logger logger;
    private PropertiesUtil pu;
    TestLogger()
    {
        
        System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile","log4j2.properties");
        logger =   LogManager.getLogger(TestLogger.class);
        logger.info("Yes I am there!");
        logger.debug("I am debugging!");
        logger.warn("giving you a warner!");
        
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestLogger z = new TestLogger();
        

    }}
```

I have created a reference of PropertiesUtil but anyways I am not using it.

when I am executing this program nothing is shown on console. as I could make out, I am not able to load properties file properly.

suggest me any modifications or alternatives with examples.

Thanks in advance!

[image: project Structure]

Answer (score 0):

Without any feedback on the error you are getting, I can guess that one of the problems is with the file name. You should specify the absolute path to your log4j2.properties file when you are setting the system property:

```
System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile","/absolute/path/to/log4j2.properties");
```

In this way the logger system will know exactly where to find your file.

Comment: still not working. System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/resources/log4j.properties"); I gave the right path to fetch log4j.properties.

Comment: by the way i created a folder called as resources and kept properties file in that folder.

Comment: when I removed System.setProperty() line I get error as ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
 so i renamed that file as log4j.configurationFile but still not working

Comment: after you have set the property, you can check what is its value, try to do that with System.getProperty("log4j.configurationFile") and print it to the console with System.out.println() so that you can check that the path is the correct one.